# Facebook Deep linking for android app

Tags: android, facebook, applinks

I have a application and i have facebook page for the same.now whenever a user clicks on Use app(call to action) button on android device whether it is facebook android app or user is logged in from browser I need to open my app installed in user's phone.

I have searched so much but came across some old posts as facebook has introduces applinks.org meanwhile.
So I am not getting how to do this thing.

Comment: Check here http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 1):

When you're setting up the Call To Action button on your page, you need to select `App`:

[image]

Then you will fill in a URL using your app's custom URL scheme in the **Deep Link** box (that's what actually launches your app on the visitor's device), and the package name of your app in the **Package Name** box (I believe Google uses this for verification purposes).

If you haven't set up a custom URL scheme yet, [this Facebook docs page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/add-to-content) explains how. That will take care of *opening* the app (`myApp://`), but if you're wanting to go to a specific piece of content (`myApp://path/to/content`), then you also need to follow [these directions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/android).